# Elegant proof for a statement

Tags: matrices

Given the matrix $$A=\begin{pmatrix}
 0 &  1 & 1\\
 1 & 0 &  1\\
1 &  1 &  0
\end{pmatrix}$$ Is there an elegant way to prove that $$(A-I_{3})^{-1}-A^{-1}=(A-I_{3})^{-1}A^{-1} ?$$ 
Note: It's easy to just calculate it, but I suspect it can be done by a nice approach.

Comment: As pointed out in some of the answers, the relationship does not depend on any particular form of $A$. All you need is the existence of the inverses of $A$ and $A-I$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(A-I)^{-1}(A-I) = I \Rightarrow\\
(A-I)^{-1}A - (A-I)^{-1} = I \Rightarrow\\
(A-I)^{-1}A - (A-I)^{-1} = A^{-1}A \Rightarrow\\
\left[(A-I)^{-1}-A^{-1}\right]A = (A-I)^{-1} \Rightarrow \\
\left[(A-I)^{-1}-A^{-1}\right]AA^{-1} = (A-I)^{-1}A^{-1} \Rightarrow \\
(A-I)^{-1}-A^{-1} = (A-I)^{-1}A^{-1}.$$

Notice that this does not depend upon the the dimension on $A$, nor on its particular form. It is only asked that both $A$ and $A-I$ are invertible.

Answer (score 2):

Multiply on both sides from the left by $A(A-I)$. Then multiply from the right by $A(A-I)$, and you get something you can confirm without calculating any inverses.

Comment: Since we have (implicitly) assumed that both $A$ and $A-I$ are invertible, multiplying by those two matrices doesn't introduce any extra solutions, so if the equality you get are multiplying is true, the original equality is also true.

Answer (score 2):

$A+I$ has rank $1$ and eigenvalues $0,0,3$. It follows that $A$ has eigenvalues $-1,-1,2$ and the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is given by $(x+1)^2(x-2)$. In particular neither $0$ or $1$ belong to the spectrum of $A$ and 
$$ \frac{1}{A-I}-\frac{1}{A} = \frac{1}{A(A-I)} $$
holds as a consequence of $\frac{1}{x-1}-\frac{1}{x}=\frac{1}{x(x-1)}$ for any $x\not\in\{0,1\}$.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}(A-I_{3})^{-1}-A^{-1}=(A-I_{3})^{-1}A^{-1}&\iff(A-I_3)(A-I_3)^{-1}A-(A-I_3)A^{-1}A=I_3\\&\iff A-(A-I_3)=I_3.\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

It means that $\;(A-I)^{-1}-A^{-1}=\bigl(A(A-I)\bigr)^{-1}$, so compute the product
$$A(A-I)\bigl((A-I)^{-1}-A^{-1}\bigr)= A(A-I)(A-I)^{-1}-A(A-I)A^{-1}=A-A(A-I)A^{-1}.$$
Now note $A$ and $A-I$ commute, so
$$A-A(A-I)A^{-1}=A-AA^{-1}(A-I)=A-(A-I)=I.$$
Similar computation for $\;\bigl((A-I)^{-1}-A^{-1}\bigr)A(A-I)$.